# Get image in Razor from folder in project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have project for API where I generate pdf using Razor template

Here is project structure

[image]

I included `StaticFiles` in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Images")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
        });
```

And in razor template, I try to use it like this

```
<img class="logo"
     height="80"
     src="@ViewData["BaseUrl"]/Images/propertyLogo-dark.png"/>
```

But in pdf image not visible, like it not visible under this path.

What can be my problem?

Comment: Pdf file generate run time?

Comment: using jsReport @jishansiddique

Comment: So you need to write image in canvas after generate pdf file

Comment: okay, how I can do this?@jishansiddique

Comment: For pdf file generate you are using jquery?

Comment: I using jsReport I wrote it before@jishansiddique

Comment: Please check here https://forum.jsreport.net/topic/400/asp-net-core-image-in-pdf-header

Comment: It's not related @jishansiddique

Answer (score 0):

```
"@ViewData["BaseUrl"]/Images/propertyLogo-dark.png" // should be /StaticFiles/ instead Images
```

Comment: Not helps. Still not see the image in pdf