# Razor class library empty image - ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, pdf, razor, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

Currently I'm trying to generate a PDF file (DinkToPdf) from a `.cshtml` file, however my company's logo won't display. The image is already missing in the htmlcontent string, so I expect that the Razor class library can't access the image.

Project setup:

[Project setup (company name blurred out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe5dT.png)

- `ContainerManagementService.ManagementService.WebApi` is the startup project.
- `ContainerManagementService.ManagementService.WebApi.Rai` is where the controller is called.
- `ContainerManagementService.ManagementService.WebApi.Pdf` is where I want to place all the PDF logic (more templates to come)

`ContainerManagementService.Infrastructure.Pdf` is where the magic happens.

**Step 1** is retrieving the `.cshtml` (found online while searching for the solution):

```
    public string RenderPartialToString<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();
        var partial = FindView(actionContext, partialName);

        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                partial,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            partial.RenderAsync(viewContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }

    private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string partialName)
    {
        var getPartialResult = _viewEngine.GetView(null, partialName, true);

        if (getPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return getPartialResult.View;
        }

        var findPartialResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, partialName, true);

        if (findPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return findPartialResult.View;
        }

        var searchedLocations = getPartialResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findPartialResult.SearchedLocations);
        var errorMessage = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            new[] { $"Unable to find partial '{partialName}'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations)); ;
        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
    }

    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = _serviceProvider
        };
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
```

[File structure project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAeOX.png)

This works perfectly fine, however when I inspect the `htmlContent`, the image is empty :

```
var invoiceViewModel = new InvoiceViewModel(request.OrderSummaries, request.DateTime);
var htmlContent = _razorRendererHelper.RenderPartialToString("/Views/Shared/OrderSummaryTemplate.cshtml", invoiceViewModel);

return GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
```

[Empty image in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Nmv.png)

```
@model InvoiceViewModel

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container {
            width: 90%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        .brand-section {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .row{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        img{
            width : 55px;
            height : 55px;
            background-color : white;
        }

        .company-details {
            float: right;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .body-section {
            padding: 16px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .heading {
            font-size: 17px;
            margin-bottom: 08px;
        }

        .sub-heading {
            color: #262626;
            margin-bottom: 05px;
        }

        table {
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

            table thead tr {
                border: 1px solid #111;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
            }

            table td {
                vertical-align: middle !important;
                text-align: center;
            }

            table th, table td {
                padding-top: 08px;
                padding-bottom: 08px;
            }

        .table-bordered {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px gray;
        }

            .table-bordered td, .table-bordered th {
                border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
            }

        .text-right {
            text-align: end;
        }

        .w-20 {
            width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mogee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="brand-section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6" style="width: 60px; display: inline-block;">
                        <img src="logo.jpg" class="img" alt="My image"/>
                </div>
                <div style="width:60px; display: inline-block;"></div>
                <div class="col-6" style= "width: 630px;display: inline-block;">
                    <div class="company-details">
                        <p class="text-white"></p>
                        <p class="text-white"></p>
                        <p class="text-white"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-section">
            <h3 class="heading">Bestelde producten overzicht @Model.InvoiceDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</h3>
            <br>
            <table class="table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Klant</th>
                        <th class="w-10">Product code</th>
                        <th class="w-25">Product naam</th>
                        <th class="w-10">Prijs</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
                    {
                        int count = 0;
                        var orders = Model.OrderSummaries.Where(o => o.CustomerId == customer);

                        foreach (var order in orders)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@order.CustomerName</td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductId</td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductName</td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductPrice</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductId</td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductName</td>
                                    <td>@order.ProductPrice</td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Totaal</td>
                        <td>@Model.TotalPrice</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="body-section">
            <p>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried most of the combinations with the src :

```
~/StaticFiles/images/logo.jpg

Url.Content(~/StaticFiles/images/logo.jpg)

Url.Content(/StaticFiles/images/logo.jpg)
```

Set static file to 'StaticFiles' :

```
internal class EditorRCLConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<StaticFileOptions>
{
    [Obsolete]
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    [Obsolete]
    public EditorRCLConfigureOptions(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, StaticFileOptions options)
    {
        options.ContentTypeProvider = options.ContentTypeProvider ?? new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

        if (options.FileProvider == null && _environment.WebRootFileProvider == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Missing FileProvider.");
        }

        options.FileProvider = options.FileProvider ?? _environment.WebRootFileProvider;

        var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, "StaticFiles");
        options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(options.FileProvider, filesProvider);
    }
}
```

When I enable "Directory browsing", I can see the images.

When I change the `img` `src` to a local path (`c:/user/git/...`), the image does load.

What could be the problem? Am I looking into the right direction?

Links of what I have tried :

- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5296270/ASP-NET-Core-3-x-Dynamically-Loadable-Plugins-with
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consume-content-from-a-referenced-rcl-1
- [Get image in Razor from folder in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801066/get-image-in-razor-from-folder-in-project)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve files outside of web root,you can try to use the configuration:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "StaticFiles")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});
```

and then use:

```
<img src="~/StaticFiles/images/logo.jpg" />
```

For more detials,you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

If it still does not work,you can try to use:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine("c:/user/git/...")),
    RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
});//adding absolute route here
```